# Highlight all the div currently shown in scroll window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some div with same class but different height. I want to add a highlight class on all the div currently showing in my current window frame (the window frame is scroll-able).

I tried this code

```
$('.l3_box').each(function () {
    var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
    var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

    /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
    if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
        $('#tab_out01 .l3_box').removeClass("testt");
        $(this).addClass("testt");

    }
});
```

This works fine when my div size is equal or less than the size of the window.
But its not working when my div size is much higher than the size of the window until I go to the end of the div.

Comment: create a fiddle

Comment: @Ish I can not create the fiddle the code i have because its dynamic but here it the slimier one with the issue. Please try on it.
http://jsfiddle.net/e5qaD/5850/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't check both, top and bottom?

```
$('#tab_out01 .l3_box').removeClass("testt");
$('.l3_box').each(function () {
    var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
    var top_of_object = $(this).offset().top;
    var center_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() / 2;

    /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
    if (bottom_of_object > center_of_window && center_of_window > top_of_object) {
        $(this).addClass("testt");
        return false; // break
    }
});
```